# Creating a 2D GtkWidget array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault, gtk, background-color

I want to create a 10x20 array of type GtkWidget. I want to make each of them a GtkEventBox in which I will attach a label.

How am I supposed to create and use a 2D GtkWidget* array?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
//global variable:
GtkWidget *labelPlate[ROWS][COLUMNS];
...
...
inside the function that creates the table and attaches the event boxes to it
//my table, where the EventBoxes will be attached to
GtkWidget *finalPlateTable = gtk_table_new (10, 20, TRUE);

int i, j;
for(i = 0; i<ROWS; i++){
    for(j=0 ; j<COLUMNS; j++){
        //Make a char with the current float and create a label with it.

        char finalString[14];
        sprintf(finalString, "%.2f", plate[i][j]);

        GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new(finalString);;

        //Labels cannot have bg color, so attach each label to an event box
        /*HERE I GET SEG FAULT*/
        labelPlate[i][j]=gtk_event_box_new();

                    //adding the label to my eventbox
        gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(labelPlate[i][j]), label);

        //Add the corresponding bg color to each event box
        GdkColor color;
        switch(scalePlate[i][j]){
                            ...
                            ...
            break;
        }
                    //coloring the event box with the corresponding background
        gtk_widget_modify_bg ( GTK_WIDGET(labelPlate[i][j]), GTK_STATE_NORMAL, &color);
                    //attach the event box to the appropriate location of my table
        gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (finalPlateTable), labelPlate[i][j], j, j+1, i, i+1);
        //show them!
        gtk_widget_show(label);
        gtk_widget_realize(labelPlate[i][j]);
    }
}
//adding the table to my vertical box, and show both of them
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX (verticalBox), finalPlateTable, TRUE, TRUE, 10);

gtk_widget_show (finalPlateTable);
gtk_widget_show (verticalBox);
```

I would like to point out that I am fairly new to **C** and I don't know how to use `malloc` (but I suspect that I should make use of it, now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

Initialize array as:

```
GtkWidget **myarray;
myarray = g_new(GtkWidget *, ROWS*COLUMNS);
```

then access specific row and column using the function:

```
int returnPosAt(int row, int column){
    return row*COLUMNS+column;
}
```

so, then, you can call

```
myarray[returnPosAt(i, j)]=gtk_event_box_new();
```

So, actually you have an 1D array and by calling the function you get the corresponding 1D pos of your 2D position (i, j).